# Django - Best way to create snapshots of objects

Tags: python, django

I am currently working on a Django 2+ project involving a blockchain, and I want to make copies of some of my object's states into that blockchain.

Basically, I have a model (say "contract") that has a list of several "signature" objects.

I want to make a snapshot of that contract, with the signatures. What I am basically doing is taking the contract at some point in time (when it's created for example) and building a JSON from it.

My problem is: I want to update that snapshot anytime a signature is added/updated/deleted, and each time the contract is modified.

The intuitive solution would be to override each "delete", "create", "update" of **each** of the models involved in that snapshot, and pray that all of them the are implemented right, and that I didn't forget any. But I think that this is not scalable at all, hard to debug and ton maintain.

I have thought of a solution that might be more centralized: using a periodical job to get the last update date of my object, compare it to the date of my snapshot, and update the snapshot if necessary.

**However** with that solution, I can identify changes when objects are modified or created, but not when they are deleted.

So, this is my big question mark: how with django can you identify deletions in relationships, without any prior context, just by looking at the current database's state ? Is there a django module to record deleted objects ? What are your thoughts on my issue ?

Answer (score 2):

All right?

I think that, as I understand your problem, you are in need of a module like Django Signals, which listens for changes in the database and, when identified (and if all the desired conditions are met), executes certain commands in your application ( even be able to execute in the database).

This is the most recent documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/signals/